# How to seperate legs from each other and sculpt?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, edges, scene

Well I want to sculpt genitals for my models but I dont know how to do that. I mean what is the method for it? Because I have to seperate them and work there but I couldnt find any way to do that. Can you show me some method? [image]

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is, we want to sculpt, but the legs are in the way, so we can't easily sculpt what we want to sculpt?  There are a number of solutions to this problem.  They all work slightly differently.

One thing we can do is mask the legs for purposes of sculpting.  We can select a mask brush, then sculpt over the legs with that brush, making them progressively more transparent.  If we do that, any further sculpting we do (with regular brushes) won't affect the masked areas, to the proportion that we've actually marked them with a mask brush.

For a less gradated approach, we can just say, no, just don't sculpt the legs!  Period.  No, exclamation mark!  Tab into edit mode and select a bunch of leg verts and 'h' to hide them.  Now switch back to sculpt mode and start sculpting, and we'll see that our sculpting doesn't affect any of the vertices that we've hidden.

Okay, but let's say we don't even want to *see* the part of the mesh that we aren't sculpting.  We can do that; let's use a mask modifier.  Same thing as before, tab into edit, select a bunch of leg verts, and assign them to a new vertex group.  Then give the mesh a mask modifier, specify your vertex group to modulate that modifier, click the button to the right of the vertex group in the modifier to invert that group, and we're now hiding all those verts.  We can't sculpt them, and we can't even see them.  Tab into sculpt mode and you won't see or affect those verts.  But, you can't dynotopo at that point, because Blender won't know whether to assign dynotopo verts to the masked vertex group or not.

Are there any other ways to do this?  Sure!  We could separate the legs out to a new object, then sculpt, but, careful not to sculpt the margins, and rejoin later.  Or, we could sculpt a whole new object, then boolean union it with our original mesh.  There are a ton of different techniques.  Each one is slightly different in how it works; it's best to understand all of them so that you can use whichever is going to make your current problem the easiest to solve.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I move legs without rigging them? Like move them and sculpt than take back to their last position? Sorry for my english btw.

Comment: Taking them back to their last position is the hard part, and I'd recommend just rigging them if you need to do that.  Otherwise, yes, you can move them with a pose brush.